# Limit of a integral $\,\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt \right)^3}{\int_{0}^x te^{t^2}\mathrm dt} $

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I want to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt \right)^3} {\displaystyle\int_{0}^x te^{t^2}\mathrm dt}
$$

I have tried to solve it by using L'hopital but due to chain rule I still have an integral on the numerator

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule twice.

Answer (score 4):

We can avoid l'Hopital rule. Let $ f(x)$ denote the expression under the limit sign. Then $f(-x)=f(x).$ It suffices to consider  $x>0 .$ Then $f(x)>0.$ The numerator is less than or equal $x^3e^{3x^2},$ while the denominator is equal ${1\over 2}[e^{x^2}-1].$ Next $${3x^2\over e^{3x^2}-1}\to 1,\quad x^2\to 0$$ Hence the limit of the original expression is equal $0.$

Another solution can be obtained by observing that for a function $g(x)$ continuous at $0,$ we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x}\int\limits_0^xg(t)\,dt = g(0),\quad \lim_{x\to 0}{1\over x^2}\int\limits_0^xtg(t)\,dt = {1\over 2}g(0)$$ We can apply that to $g(t)=e^{t^2}.$  in this way we obtain $$\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}=2$$

Answer (score 2):

If the limits below exist, then you can rewrite your limit as
$$ \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0}{\int_{0}^x e^{t^2} dt \over x}\bigg)^3 \bigg(\lim_{x \to 0}{x^3 \over \int_{0}^x te^{t^2} dt}\bigg)
$$

L'hopital gives both limits in short order.

Answer (score 1):

By inequality,

$$0 < \dfrac {\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt \right)^3} {\displaystyle\int_{0}^x te^{t^2}\mathrm dt} < \dfrac {(xe^{x^2})^3} {\frac{x}{2}e^{(x/2)^2}} = 2x^2e^{3x^2-x^2/4}$$

Hence, the limit is zero by the squeeze theorem.